# copy images to folder using c#

Tags: c#

I have a client requirment where I have a csv  file which has these  entries

```
"2","0000000255","2014-03-11T18:44:53","2014-03-11T18:47:15","1"," ","KP54OXZ","Addenbrooks Hospital","-1","-1","entry_153_KP54OXZ_2014-03-14_13-56-06.jpg","exit_153_KP54OXZ_2014-03-14_13-56-06.jpg"

    entry_153_KP54OXZ_2014-03-14_13-56-06.jpg
    exit_153_KP54OXZ_2014-03-14_13-56-06.jpg
```

I need to create to new folder  for every such vrm like  "KP54OXZ"   and move the images to the respective folder.

what i tried ..

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(@"C:\\Users\\IT-Administrator\\Desktop\\fg\\fg.csv");
        parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
        parser.SetDelimiters(",");
        while (!parser.EndOfData)
        {
            //Process row
            string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();
            foreach (string field in fields)
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(@"I:\\kiran\\hhh\" + fields);
            }
        }
        parser.Close();
    }
    }
}
```

but i am not succesfull in creating and moving. ANy help is needed.

Comment: "not successful" means... what? Runtime error? Nothing happens? Did you try debugging?

Comment: are you getting any errors?

Comment: I don't see that you are parsing the lines from the CSV...you're tacking the entire line into a path and trying to copy with it...  Doesn't that mean a path of:  I:\\smrithi\\hhh\"2","0000000255","2014-03-11T18:44:53","2014-03-11T18:47:15","1"," ","KP54OXZ","Addenbrooks Hospital","-1","-1","entry_153_KP54OXZ_2014-03-14_13-56-06.jpg","exit_153_KP54OXZ_2014-03-14_13-56-06.jpg"

Comment: The given path's format is not supported. i receive this error

Comment: @smrithi - because you are trying to copy it to a folder with the name of the CSV's text which also contains some invalid letters

Comment: What is the path "C:\MyImages\"?  Is this what you are prompting for?  Where are the TO and FROM folders, and how do you get them?

Comment: I have edited the code and parsed my csv file and trying to create a new folder

Answer (score 0):

A folder's name cannot contain any of the following characters:
\ / : * ? " < > |

According to the code, you are moving the file to "C:\MyFolders\" + line

the  +line will cause it to include several of those letters therefore the folder will not be made

Comment: this was causing the error  foreach (string field in fields){ Directory.CreateDirectory(@"I:\\kiran\\hhh\" + field);} but system.string[] named folder  has been created in the I:\\kiran\\hhh

Comment: no error but unfortunately mu code is wrong it creates a folder with name as system.string[]

Comment: try changing Directory.CreateDirectory(@"I:\\kiran\\hhh\" + line); to Directory.CreateDirectory(@"I:\\kiran\\hhh\" + field);

Comment: the code you've provided in the question doesn't show that

Comment: added now  but the folder with system.string[] has been created instead of vrm name

Comment: Try debugging inside the foreach loop.. Just put a print command with the value 'field' and tell the result